# Optional command line argument in R script

Tags: r

I want to have an optional positional command-line argument to my R script and assumed this would be OK:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
infile <- args[1]
outfile <- tryCatch(args[2],
    error=function(cond) {
        "default.txt"
    }
)
```

But R doesn't error when an array is accessed beyond its length:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> x[4]
[1] NA
```

I can't use `missing` for some reason:

```
> missing(args[2])
Error in missing(args[2]) : invalid use of 'missing'
```

So how can I test for a missing second command-line argument and insert a default if necessary?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question/problem?

Comment: You can do `outfile<-if (length(args)==1) "default.txt" else args[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a vector beyond its length is not an error, and simply returns `NA`, as you've discovered.

In a function call, [`missing()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/missing.html) tests if a function parameter (also called a "formal argument") was provided with an argument by the caller, thus it is not correct to use it on something that is not a function parameter, and it is not correct to use it outside of a function body.

Here's how I would do this:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=T);
argsLen <- length(args);
if (argsLen > 2) stop('error: too many arguments.');
if (argsLen < 1) stop('error: missing infile.');
infile <- args[1];
outfile <- if (argsLen < 2) 'default.txt' else args[2];
print(infile);
print(outfile);
```

Demo:

```
./script.r;
## Error: error: missing infile.
## Execution halted

./script.r a;
## [1] "a"
## [1] "default.txt"

./script.r a b;
## [1] "a"
## [1] "b"

./script.r a b c;
## Error: error: too many arguments.
## Execution halted
```